# Scatter tensor in pytorch along the rows

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensor, scatter

I want to scatter tensors in granularities of rows.

For example consider,

```
Input = torch.tensor([[2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]])
```

I want to scatter

```
S = torch.tensor([[1,2],[1,2]])
```

to indices

```
I = torch.tensor([0,2])
```

I expect the output to be `torch.tensor([[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2]])`.

Here `S[0]` is scattered to Input`[I[0]]`, similarly `S[1]` is scattered to `Input[I[1]]`

How can I achieve this? Instead of looping over the row in `S`, I am looking for a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do  `input[I] = S`

Example:

```
input = torch.tensor([[2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]])
S = torch.tensor([[1,2],[1,2]])
I = torch.tensor([0,2])
```

```
input[I] = S
input
tensor([[1, 2],
        [3, 4],
        [1, 2]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer might be a little late, but anyway, you could do:

```
import torch

inp = torch.tensor([[2,3], [3,4], [4,5]])
src = torch.tensor([[1,2], [1,2]])
idxs = torch.tensor([[0,0],[2,2]])

y = torch.scatter(inp, 0, idxs, src)
```